# Unable to create click event handler from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

Not so sure why I could not create click event handler from getElementsByClassName. I could populate and see all the rendered html for all the products with class name `AddToCart` for the button. But `addToCart` is null at `var addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName("AddToCart");`

```js
var productList = [
    { id: 101, product: "Logitech Mouse", unitprice: 45.0 },
    { id: 102, product: "Logitech Keyboard", unitprice: 50.0 },
    { id: 103, product: "HP Mouse", unitprice: 35.0 }
  ];

  const populateProducts = object => {
    // Start our HTML
    var html = "";
    debugger;
    // Loop through members of the object
    object.forEach(function(item) {
      html += `<div class="column"><div class="card">\
                <h2>${item.product}</h2>
                <p class="price">RM ${item.unitprice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                <p><button class=AddToCart>Add to Cart</button></p></div></div>`;
    });
    debugger;
    var addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName("AddToCart");

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(addToCart, function(element) {
      element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(element);
      });
    });
    return html;
  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("productRow").innerHTML = populateProducts(
      productList
    );
  });
```

```html
<div id="productRow"></div>
```

And how do I grab `item.id` upon clicking "AddToCart" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to hook up the event handler before the elements exist in the DOM. You need to move that code hooking up the handlers to *after* the code assigning the HTML to `innerHTML`.

Then, you can store the item ID as a `data-*` attribute on the button, and access it via `.getAttribute("data-id")` (or `.dataset.id` on modern browsers):

```js
var productList = [
    { id: 101, product: "Logitech Mouse", unitprice: 45.0 },
    { id: 102, product: "Logitech Keyboard", unitprice: 50.0 },
    { id: 103, product: "HP Mouse", unitprice: 35.0 }
  ];

  const populateProducts = object => {
    // Start our HTML
    var html = "";
    // Loop through members of the object
    object.forEach(function(item) {
      html += `<div class="column"><div class="card">\
                <h2>${item.product}</h2>
                <p class="price">RM ${item.unitprice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                <p><button class=AddToCart data-id="${item.id}">Add to Cart</button></p></div></div>`;
    });
    return html;
  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("productRow").innerHTML = populateProducts(
      productList
    );
    var addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName("AddToCart");

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(addToCart, function(element) {
      element.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("via getAttribute:", element.getAttribute("data-id"));
        console.log("via dataset:", element.dataset.id);
      });
    });
  });
```

```html
<div id="productRow"></div>
```

Note that you don't need a separate event handler for each button, you can reuse a single function:

```js
var productList = [
    { id: 101, product: "Logitech Mouse", unitprice: 45.0 },
    { id: 102, product: "Logitech Keyboard", unitprice: 50.0 },
    { id: 103, product: "HP Mouse", unitprice: 35.0 }
  ];

  const populateProducts = object => {
    // Start our HTML
    var html = "";
    // Loop through members of the object
    object.forEach(function(item) {
      html += `<div class="column"><div class="card">\
                <h2>${item.product}</h2>
                <p class="price">RM ${item.unitprice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                <p><button class=AddToCart data-id="${item.id}">Add to Cart</button></p></div></div>`;
    });
    return html;
  };

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("productRow").innerHTML = populateProducts(
      productList
    );
    var addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName("AddToCart");
    
    function handler() {
      console.log("via getAttribute:", this.getAttribute("data-id"));
      console.log("via dataset:", this.dataset.id);
    }

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(addToCart, function(element) {
      element.addEventListener("click", handler);
    });
  });
```

```html
<div id="productRow"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The elements you want are not in the DOM - you've only created a *string*, which happens to contain HTML markup, but the elements are not in the DOM, so they can't be selected with `getElementsByClassName` (or anything else) yet.

Instead of creating just a string, consider create the *actual elements* with `createElement`, and then by appending each element to a container. Then you can use selection methods on the created element to get to the button, and add the event listeners:

```js
var productList = [{
    id: 101,
    product: "Logitech Mouse",
    unitprice: 45.0
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    product: "Logitech Keyboard",
    unitprice: 50.0
  },
  {
    id: 103,
    product: "HP Mouse",
    unitprice: 35.0
  }
];

const populateProducts = (container, arrOfObjects) => {
  
  // Start our HTML
  var html = "";
  debugger;
  // Loop through members of the object
  arrOfObjects.forEach(function(item) {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.className = 'column';
    newDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="card">\
                <h2>${item.product}</h2>
                <p class="price">RM ${item.unitprice.toFixed(2)}</p>
                <p><button>Add to Cart</button></p></div>`;
    newDiv.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(item.id);
    });
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
  });
};

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  populateProducts(document.getElementById("productRow"), productList);
});
```

```html
<div id="productRow"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. May I know the benefit of using `createElement`? ya I realize `createElement` can do the same but can't think of the benefit of it yet. The reason I am using the current way is because I feel that it is more readable.

Comment: `createElement` gives you an *element* in return, and you can do many things with elements that you can't do with plain HTML strings - like add event listeners, among other things.